# VPN send but not receive data

Tags: macos, vpn

My VPN service works perfect until last friday and still working on a DD-WRT router. I'm using OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion. Here is the log output http://pastebin.com/QZyz3eSf

Others connections works fine also another VPN connections.

All started playing with this

> How to auto connect to VPN upon login/boot? - Ask Different http://s.cipr.es/OT1Ues

Answer (score 1):

I fix it playing with `~/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`

Comment: What exactly did you change there?